# Who is speaking in this Star Trek: Discovery second season teaser?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, spock, actor-identification

This teaser recently was published

([Alternate link for some regions](https://youtu.be/K117prND4K0))

As we can see, there are uniforms in the works that are much more faithful to the original series.  And we know that the USS Enterprise NCC-1701 will play a part as it was teased in the last few moments of the first season.  Furthermore, it has been confirmed that [Spock will appear](https://nerdist.com/star-trek-discovery-spock-season-2/) at least in a flashback.

Now, there's a voice in the video that seems to me is supposed to be Spock's.  So I'm wondering if that's the case?

**Whose voices are delivering the lines in the Discovery season 2 preview?**
Which can we positively identify and whose are unknown and rife for speculation?

Comment: Sounds like Burnham, Spock and Pike. Odd that the uniform they showed was the TOS version - it should reasonably be the Cage / Where No Man Has Gone Before version. Ah well, add it to the pile of other inconsistencies.

Comment: Does "This video is not available" mean that it is region-restricted?

Comment: @Gaultheria, it still works for me, so I believe so.  What's your region?   Can anyone supply a different link?

Comment: I'm in western Canada.  I can view [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K117prND4K0), which seems like it must be the same video.

Comment: @Gaultheria, added alternate link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The voices, in addition to Burnham, are those of Pike, Spock, and Sarek:

## Jeffrey Hunter as Capt. Pike from "The Cage"

One of the voices is Capt. Pike, played by Jeffrey Hunter, extracted directly from the *TOS* original pilot **"The Cage"**:

> **PIKE:** You bet I'm tired. You bet. I'm tired of being responsible for two hundred and three lives. I'm tired of deciding which mission is too risky and which isn't, and who's going on the landing party and who doesn't, and who lives and who dies.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/1.htm))

## Leonard Nimoy as Spock from "Space Seed" and "The Immunity Syndrome"

One of the sound clips of Spock that we hear is from *TOS* **"Space Seed"**:

> **SPOCK:** Insufficient facts always invite danger, Captain.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/24.htm))

We also hear the following from **"The Immunity Syndrome"**, in which Spock accuses McCoy:

> **SPOCK:** You speak about the objective hardness of the Vulcan heart, yet how little room there seems to be in yours.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/48.htm))

## Sarek, as portrayed by James Frain in *Discovery*

We also hear James Frain's Sarek:

> **SAREK:**  I see an outsider. The child molded by wisdom and human compassion.

A script search confirms that this particular piece of dialogue does not appear in any Season 1 episode and so it is either discarded dialogue from Season 1, dialogue that may be included in a Season 2 episode, or something that was produced expressly for this teaser.  A number of news sites agree that the voice belongs to Frain (e.g. [TrekToday](https://www.trektoday.com/content/2018/04/star-trek-discovery-season-two-teaser/)).

Comment: Oh, it ***is*** Leonard Nimoy!  It didn't even occur to me they could/would use old dialog so I thought it was just an exceptionally good impersonation!  And I thought someone was going to slap the Future Works policy on me.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Can't beat the real thing.